# Garbage collection with a generic stack

Tags: vb.net, silverlight-4.0, garbage-collection

I'm writing a multiple undo/redo system for a custom textbox control in Silverlight.  The thing I'm working on now is reducing memory consumption.

So the problem I'm having is that the stacks I'm using are being held in memory too long.

I figure it'd be relatively inexpensive to erase the stack altogether whenever its `Count` reaches 0 naturally, or when the stack is cleared due to an event.  So I'm attempting to do that with this code, hoping that'll be picked up by the GC...

```
TextHistory.Clear()
TextHistory = Nothing
```

But that's definitely not working, and this stack can potentially hold 50 MB or more.  By the way, `TextHistory` is a `Stack(Of Moment)`.  And here's the `Moment` class...

```
Public Class Moment
    Public Text As String
    Public SelectionStart As Integer
    Public SelectionLength As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByRef _Text As String, _SelectionStart As Integer, _SelectionLength As Integer)
        Text = _Text
        SelectionStart = _SelectionStart
        SelectionLength = _SelectionLength
    End Sub 
End Class
```

Comment: This *will* work. There is something that you didn't tell us that is causing the problem. You are aware that GC doesn't happen immediately?

Comment: I trust it is safe to assume you aren't holding a reference to the TextHistory stack or any of the Moment objects elsewhere?

Comment: @usr - I know that GC doesn't happen immediately, but I'm looking at both the GC.GetTotalMemory() and the actual memory usage of the entire Silverlight process, and they're holding onto all that memory for many minutes (probably forever).  I then commented out the line that pushes onto the TextHistory stack and the memory usage only increases by 2 or 3 MB (as opposed to 50) when performing the same task.

Comment: @roken - Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: Did you force a GC? GC does not happen based on time. Waiting does not help trigger it.

Comment: @usr - Yes I tried forcing a GC and that works, actually.  But I shouldn't have to do that should I?  I thought forcing the GC should be avoided as mentioned here... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/11/29/when-to-call-gc-collect.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you said that forcing a GC works (works = cleans up the garbage). That is how it is supposed to work.

GC happens on demand. Demand is either lots of allocations happened, memory pressure or manual trigger. None of these happened which is why the garbage did not get cleaned up.

GC does not run time-based (say every minute or so).

Comment: Thanks.  I thought I could encourage the GC to clean up the memory used for these strings a little sooner.  But this makes sense.  And actually, once I make the whole algorithm more efficient it won't be as big of an issue.

Comment: In your case I don't see anything wrong with forcing a GC on special occasions.

Answer (score 2):

Stack(Of T) is implemented using a T array.  At 50 MB, that array has been copied and grown many times on the large object heap which only gets collected with gen 2.  The large object heap is not compacted either, so if additional space is allocated for the array copy that space will remain allocated after the array is collected by the GC but the "holes" left will be available for other objects.

If your stack actually needs to grow this large, you could get around using the large object heap by implementing your own stack via a linked-list.

Comment: So are you saying that if I make the undo system more efficient in terms of what's stored (I'm working on it), then the garbage collector will handle this better as a result?  It's horribly inefficient right now because it's storing the entire `Text` value representing an entire snapshot in history, so to speak.  I'll be changing this to only store the `SelectedText` value, which should help drastically with memory consumption.

Comment: @SteveWortham That will help some since my guess is there is an enormous number of Moments if your stack is growing to 50MB (how did you get this number, by the way?). Your best bet is to grab a memory profiler to get a true picture of what your memory usage looks like.  You can get a free trial of ANTS from Red Gate which is an excellent tool (IMO).

Comment: @SteveWortham Its also worth noting that the size of the strings referenced by the Moment objects will not figure into the explination in my answer, since the strings themselves do not live on the LOH as part of the Moment object, they are simply referenced.

Comment: In order to get this number I compared memory usage with and without the TextHistory stack, while following the same tasks in the application.  I'm getting memory usage with the `GC.GetTotalMemory(False)` function.  And, in my test I'm working with a string that's over 100 KB, and you multiply that by all its history and you've got something big.  But its really the size of the strings more than anything else that's contributing to that.

Comment: @SteveWortham Ahh, then yes, those enormous strings will end up on the LOH and are likely your offender.

Comment: Thanks roken for your help.  usr ultimately made the lightbulb go off in my head and I realized that I should move on from this problem.  I've been working on making the algorithm more efficient.  So in effect I'm only storing the text that changes inside my `Moment` class.  There have been some bugs to work out with this approach but I think I may have just cracked it, and in my testing this is using less than 1/10th the memory and it appears to be a bit faster too.